# Jquery Validation plugin - input event

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I'm using https://jqueryvalidation.org/ plugin for form validation.
I need to enable/disable submit button depending on form validation result.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you need to disable the button
2. Listen to all Changes in the form

   ```
   $( "#myform :input" ).on('change', function(){
       var form = $( "#myform" );
       form.validate();
       if(form.valid())
           $('button).attr("disabled", false);
    });
   ```

Comment: Thank you! It seems is what I need.